# Matlab: Convert a Struct to an object

Tags: matlab, object, struct

So I have a struct in matlab and it's properties are identical to the properties of an object that I want to create. Is it possible to create an object based on the value of these structs.

Comment: If you wrote/have control over the source code for the class in question, then yes: just tweak your constructor such that it can receive such a struct as its input argument.  If you do not have control over the class implementation, then AFAIK the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough, this may actually be possible in MATLAB without access to the class implementation. What you need is to create a new object of the desired class, and then fill its properties from your `struct` (which is some weird constructor-like hack).

Setting the `public` properties is easy enough, but the `private` properties are somewhat trickier. Fortunately, this [post on UndocumentedMatlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/accessing-private-object-properties#Set) explains how to modify `private` properties of objects.

In short, this solution works by getting a pointer to the value of the property (`private` and `public` alike) and changing it directly.